# [XCTest + xcresults + allure]: Screenshots not rendered

Tags: ui-automation, reporting, xctest, allure

I am running XCTest UI automation on iOS device using following command:

```
xcodebuild build-for-testing test \
  .... \
  -resultBundlePath TestResults | xcpretty
```

I followed [Allure + XCTest Integration Tutorial](https://docs.qameta.io/allure-testops/v3-integrations/frameworks/integration-xctest/) to generate allure reports out of xcresult file. When I am serving the allure results, the screenshots are not rendered, although they are present as attachments. I have attached the screenshot of what current attachment looks like below

[image]

Do we need to perform additional processing to see the screenshots?

Note: I have confirmed that the .xcresult file generated by `xcodebuild` has no issues, because when it is opened in xcode, I can see the screenshots properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the xcresults project. Could you please create an issue in our GitHub repository? It would be really helpful if you could attach the result (in the xcresults format, not allure) of a single test run that reproduces the problem you're encountering. To do this, you might want to strip the test down to just the screenshot creation part, removing all other data.

Comment: Sure, will create!

Comment: I have same problem, can you pls add link to report and result?
Btw in my case it look like problem with Xcode 15.0.1 (in Xcode 14.3.1 - we have screenshots). And changing xcresults format for Xcode 15 +